# Redirecting based on an incoming URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I just migrated a site that was written quite a while ago to wordpress.

Doing this caused the url structure to be different now using mod-rewrite. I realized after I put the new site live that there are emails that have been sent out for customers to redeem their gift certificates from the site using the old URL.

My question is, with htaccess is there a url redirect that I can do and keep the get information with it. For example, I would need this url:

`www.test.com/redeem.php?id=123`

to redirect to:

`www.test.com/redeem/now/?id=123`

If there's no solution with `.htaccess`, does anyone have any solution for PHP?

Here's what my htaccess file looks like now:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was writing this code in the header file and it works.

```
   <?php 
   if (array_shift(explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == "/redeem.php") {
      header ('Location: /gift-certificates/redeem/?id=' . $_GET["id"] );
   }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

whether it will be like you want

```
http://test.com/redeem/now/read/2
```

the .htaccess

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

[using permalink wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Thanks for your response but that looks to be the exact same as what I have already. I would like to forward or redirect urls to a different url that wordpress has chosen for the structure.